# How to exclude date type columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe with following type of columns.

```
EmployeeID   Name   DOB         Age
12345        xyz    1998/26/03  25.0   
56789        abc    2000/05/10  27.0

`dtypes EmployeeID: int64 
 Name: object DOB: datetime64[ns] Age: float64
```

I want exclude datetime and object type column from dataframe
I tried below code

```
Lst = list(df.columns)
for columnIndex, colName in enumerate(lst):
    if(df[colName].dtypes != 'object' and df[colName].dtypes != np.datetime64):
        print(df[colName])
```

But not getting expected output. Can anyone please suggest solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) in `exclude` mode:

```
out = df.select_dtypes(exclude=(object, 'datetime'))
```

output:

```
   EmployeeID   Age
0       12345  25.0
1       56789  27.0
```